# How do I avoid flickering specs when using Vue with Rails?

Tags: vue.js, rspec, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

We've recently been integrating Vue into our Rails app, but this is causing a lot of flickering Capybara/rspec tests, which as far as I can see come from race conditions where some or all Vue elements aren't rendered by the time the next Capybara action/expectation kicks in, or possibly are getting rendered but are somehow obscuring the element.

The sorts of errors I'm seeming are these:

```
element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (392, 641)
    (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.90)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError)
```

and these:

```
element click intercepted: Element <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" data-disable-with="Sign In" class="btn -light -full -solid"> is not clickable at point (272, 37). Other element would receive the click: <div class="site-header__menu__container | container gutter-lg">...</div>
    (Session info: headless chrome=77.0.3865.90)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementClickInterceptedError)
```

(possibly worth mentioning that the coordinates given when these tests fail are different from one failure to the next)

Given that the Vue elements start as 0-height  tags that might be underneath our site menu (itself a Vue component), I *think* these two errors have the same cause - ie the element we're targeting not having been (fully?) rendered yet, so I'll just show the code for one for brevity's sake - though let me know if you think I'm wrong, and I'll edit in or create a new post for the other.

I've tried the methods from two posts dealing with this kind of issue inasmuch as I can - https://engineering.gusto.com/eliminating-flaky-ruby-tests/ and https://thoughtbot.com/blog/write-reliable-asynchronous-integration-tests-with-capybara - but neither seems to have had much effect (though I'm not sure what to do in place of the 'visit' method the first one condemns, which is at the core of most feature tests).

Here's the relevant feature code for the first:

```
@vcr
@javascript
Scenario: Successfully pledging after something like confirming my account
  Given something like I am on the pledge form
  When I submit a valid pledge
  Then I should land on the HelloSign signature page
```

Implemented thusly:

```
Given("something like I am on the pledge form") do
  FactoryBot.create(:user, email: test_user_email, password: test_user_password)
  test_user.confirm
  step 'something like I have signed up and confirmed'
  user = User.last
  user.confirm
  login_as(user, scope: :user)
  visit new_pledge_path
end

When("I submit a valid pledge") do
  fill_in('pledge_pledgor_home_postcode', with: 'Up a tree, cutting mistletoe')
  fill_in('First name', with: "Asterix")
  fill_in('Surname', with: "deGaulle")
  fill_in('Phone number', with: '2345678')
  fill_in('Home address', with: 'A quiet village near the fortified Roman camp')
  fill_in('City', with: 'Totorum')

  fill_in('pledge_companies_attributes_0_name', with: 'Circvmbendibvs Wheels')
  fill_in('pledge_companies_attributes_0_number', with: '1')

  # Minor hack to be able to select options given the JS Choices library's obfuscation:
  find('#country-code-select-wrapper .choices').click
  find('#choices--pledge_pledgor_phone_code-item-choice-3').click
  find('#country-select-wrapper .choices').click
  find('#choices--pledge_pledgor_home_country-item-choice-10').click

  # Defocus the dropdowns before submitting:
  find("body").click

  # Need to activate this wrapping block, run once, then remove it when
  # refreshing the cassette. This seems dumb - would be nice to find a better solution
  # accept_alert do

  click_button('Review & Submit') ## unless ENV['IS_CIRCLE'].present?

  # end
end
```

The button itself isn't a Vue element, but there are various others above it on the page:

```
<%= form_for @pledge, html: { class: "standard-form | standard-form-base", id: 'pledge-form' } do |f| %>
  <!-- pledge errors - plain html
  <%= render "layouts/components/form_feedback" %>

  <!--  Sub Section Header - again just html -->
  <%= render "layouts/components/sub-section-header.html", content: @new_pledge_page.about_you %>

  <!--  @new_pledge_page is a Contentful Model object that -->
  <%= render "pledge_fields", content: @new_pledge_page.pledge_fields, f: f %>
<% end %>
```

And the _pledge_fields.html.erb partial:

```
<!--  Group  -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field-group">
    <%= f.label :pledgor_first_name, content.first_name, class: "standard-label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :pledgor_first_name, value: @pf_presenter.forenames_estimate %>
  </div>
</div>

<!--  Group  -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field-group">
    <%= f.label :pledgor_surname, content.surname, class: "standard-label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :pledgor_surname, value: @pf_presenter.surname_estimate %>
  </div>
</div>

<!--  Group  -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field-group | w-2/5" id="country-code-select-wrapper">
    <label class="standard-label" for="country">
      <%= content.phone_code %>
    </label>
    <select_box :opt="{ variant: '-standard -md', id: 'pledge_pledgor_phone_code', name: 'pledge[pledgor_phone_code]', value: '<%= f.object.pledgor_phone_code.presence || "1" %>' }">
      <%= @pf_presenter.country_phone_code_options %>
    </select_box>
  </div>
  <div class="field-group | w-3/5">
    <%= f.label :pledgor_phone_number, content.phone_number, class: "standard-label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :pledgor_phone_number, placeholder: "(000) 000-0000" %>
  </div>
</div>

<!--  Group  -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field-group" id="country-select-wrapper">
    <label class="standard-label" for="country">
      <%= content.country %>
    </label>
    <select_box :opt="{ variant: '-standard -md', id: 'pledge_pledgor_home_country', name: 'pledge[pledgor_home_country]', value: '<%= f.object.pledgor_home_country.presence || "US" %>' }">
      <%= @pf_presenter.country_options(pledge: f.object) %>
    </select_box>
  </div>
</div>

<!--  Group  -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field-group">
    <%= f.label :pledgor_home_address, content.home_address, class: "standard-label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :pledgor_home_address %>
  </div>
</div>

<!--  Group  -->
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="field-group | w-1/3">
    <%= f.label :pledgor_home_city, content.city, class: "standard-label" %>
    <%= f.text_field :pledgor_home_city %>
  </div>
  <div class="field-group | w-2/3">
    <% if @pf_presenter.probably_based_in?('us') %>
    <%= f.label :pledgor_home_postcode, content.zip_code, class: "standard-label" %>
    <% else %>
    <%= f.label :pledgor_home_postcode, content.postcode, class: "standard-label" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_field :pledgor_home_postcode %>
  </div>
</div>

<% if !@user.campaign %>
  <!--  Sub Section Header  -->
  <%= render "layouts/components/sub-section-header.html", content: content.company_details_subheader %>

  <%= render "company_fields", content: content.company_details, f: f %>
<% end %>

<!--  Sub Section Header  -->
<%= render "layouts/components/sub-section-header.html", content: content.how_much_subheader %>

<!-- :id="pledge_percentage" -->
<!--  Range Slider  -->
<range_slider :opt="{ id: 'pledge_percentage', name: 'pledge[percentage]' }" :min="2" :start="<%= f.object.percentage || 40 %>" :max="100" class="form-block">
</range_slider>

<!--  Sub Section Header  -->
<%= render "layouts/components/sub-section-header.html", content: content.confirmation_subheader %>

<% if !current_user.try :OptedIntoComms__c %>
<div class="<%= 'hidden' if !@pf_presenter.assumed_in_eu? %>" id="js-gdpr-input">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="field-group">
      <%= f.check_box :receive_comms, checked: false, disabled: !@pf_presenter.assumed_in_eu? %>
      <%= f.label :receive_comms, "#{content.gdpr_label}", class: "standard-label -checkbox" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% else %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :receive_comms, value: true %>
<% end %>

<%= f.hidden_field :id %>

<%= f.submit content.review_submit, class: "btn -light -full -solid", id: "submit-pledge" %>
```

Some possibly relevant specs from our Gemfile:

```
ruby "2.6.1"
gem "rails", "5.1.6.2"
gem "rspec-rails", "~> 3.7.2"
gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.1.2'
gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 3.142.4'
gem "capybara", "~> 3.22.0"
```

Comment: What version of Capybara are you using?

Comment: I've edited in the answer (plus some other possibly relevant version info) to the OP

Comment: Start by updating Capybara to the latest

Answer (score 1):

From what you mention, it seems you are using Vue in *Runtime + Compiler* mode.

As a result, the HTML elements will be available before Vue is able to compile them and make them interactive.

You could experiment using [`v-cloak`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak), a directive that will be removed once the element is compiled.

Then, in Capybara you can ensure you wait until the elements are compiled by excluding `v-cloak` elements from the results.

Example using the [`:element` selector](https://capybara-test-helpers.netlify.app/api/selectors.html#element):

```rb
find(:element, 'select_box', 'v-cloak' => nil)
```

If you need to do this often, you could extend Capybara's selectors to be able to receive an optional `vue_loaded: true` attribute:

```rb
Capybara::Selector.all.each_value do |selector|
  selector.instance_eval do
    expression_filter(:vue_loaded) do |expression|
      builder(expression).add_attribute_conditions('v-cloak': nil)
    end
    describe_expression_filters do |**options|
      if (value = options[:vue_loaded])
        " that was already compiled"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and then:

```rb
find('range_slider', vue_loaded: true)
```